# Getting tooltip/popup on fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, qtip

I'm trying to get the tooltip to popup when clicking an event on a calendar, I've started but if someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great. At the moment I get "Uncaught TypeError: element.qtip is not a function"

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate(),
       m = date.getMonth(),
       y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 550,
    header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
    today: 'today',
    month: 'month',
    week: 'week',
    day: 'day'
    },
    events: [
    <%=getcalendarevents() %>
    ],

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: event.description
        });
    },

    editable: false,
    droppable: false, 

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nothing happens when I click on the events?

Comment: Sorry wrong link please check this one http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/N78hs/

Comment: Thank you, I now get: "$(...).qtip is not a function"

Comment: Have you included all the files mentioned in External resources from jsfiddle?

Comment: qtip is not part of fullcalendar. It's a seperate script located at http://qtip2.com/

Comment: Thanks. I had included it but I moved the include to the footer and it now works? Not sure why but hey, all good.

Comment: One more thing, if I may. The end and start time show up as numbers, such as 1438530300000 and 1438532100000. Any way I can format it?

Comment: Check Moment.js (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/)